# Swift - Overlay Text on current PDF Document

Tags: swift, macos, pdf

I have been trying to simply overlay text onto a current PDF document that is essentially a timecard.  I copy the file to the downloads folder and that works fine, but then when I try to use a CGContext to add text, it exports a white PDF document. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
do {
        try fileManager.copyItem(at: pdfURL!, to: destinationURL)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Copy failed :( with error: \(error)")

    }


    if let pdf: CGPDFDocument = CGPDFDocument(destinationURL as CFURL) { // Create a PDF Document


        if pdf.numberOfPages == 1 {

            let pdfPage: CGPDFPage = pdf.page(at: 1)!

            let pageRect = pdfPage.getBoxRect(CGPDFBox.mediaBox)
            //print(pageRect)

            let context = CGContext.init(destinationURL as CFURL, mediaBox: nil, nil)

            let font = NSFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 20.0)

            let textRect = CGRect(x: 250, y: 250, width: 500, height: 40)

            let paragraphStyle: NSParagraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default

            let textColor = NSColor.black

            let textFontAttributes = [
                NSAttributedStringKey.font: font!,
                NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: textColor,
                NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
            ]

            let text: NSString = "Hello world"

            text.draw(in: textRect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

            context?.addRect(textRect)

            context?.closePDF()

        }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is what I used to overlay text on macOS.  I've been trying to find a link to the source answer I got this from.  If I find it I'll edit this answer with a link.

```
// Confirm there is a document there
if let doc: PDFDocument = PDFDocument(url: srcURL) {
    
    // Create a document, get the first page, and set the size of the page
    let page: PDFPage = doc.page(at: 0)!
    var mediaBox: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 792, height: 612)
    
    // This is where the magic happens.  Create the drawing context on the PDF
    let context = CGContext(dstURL as CFURL, mediaBox: &mediaBox, nil)
    let graphicsContext = NSGraphicsContext(cgContext: context!, flipped: false)
    NSGraphicsContext.current = graphicsContext
    
    context!.beginPDFPage(nil)
    
    // Draws the PDF into the context
    page.draw(with: .mediaBox, to: context!)
    
    // Parse and Draw Text on the context
    drawText()
    
    context!.saveGState()
    
    context!.restoreGState()
    
    context!.endPDFPage()
    NSGraphicsContext.current = nil
    context?.closePDF()
}
```